# How to traverse the mongodb(JSON) document using queries

Tags: json, mongodb, json-query

My json document is

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5b6049f845d12b6b62bf6fca"),
"original_query" : "",
}
```

I want to traverse each person who are in like field and then store their fb_id in a list using python.

I am new to mnogodb and JSON and any leads and help in building the necessary intution would be appreciated.

Edit:Code

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
import pprint


post=db.post
list_of_reactor_ids=[]
result=db.collection.find()
for doc in result:
   list_of_reactor_ids=[]
   for post in doc['posts']:
       for reactor in like['reactors']:
           list_of_reactor_ids.append(reactor[''])
print(list_of_reactor_ids)
```

Comment: you want to traverse this in javascript?

Comment: No,I am using python to traverse it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try it like so:

```
client=MongoClient('mongodb://admin:Password1@localhost:27017/iitb')
db=client.iitb # this is you selecting the database 'iitb'
list_of_reactor_ids=[]
results = db.post.find() # 'post' is the name of collection
for doc in results:
    list_of_reactor_ids = []
    for post in doc['posts']:
        if 'like' in post:
            for reactor in post['like']['reactors']:
                list_of_reactor_ids.append(reactor['fb_id'])
print(list_of_reactor_ids)
```

Comment: I tried this way but I got TypeError:'Collection' object is not iterable on the first iteration of posts

Comment: @Dumb what is the type of your json doc from mongo? Use type(doc) to find out

Comment: It sounds like the error is in how you are accessing MongoDB. You are trying to access the collection directly.

Comment: its type is <class 'pymongo.collection.Collection'>

Comment: ,does collection can't be accessed directly, how to access them?

Comment: @Dumb edited the code - I think you have selected collection twice. Note how you have to select the DB, then Collection, and then you can run 'find' on collection

Comment: It worked but now I am getting an error String indices must be integers on reactors line.

Comment: @Dumb I've made a mistake. Code corrected - try again please ;)

Comment: Thanks,it worked ,I have a doubt ,in cases if key which is "like" is not present then it is giving key error,what to do in those cases?

Comment: I have added a test - see above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178109/discussion-between-dumb-and-tony-sepia).